# Contar quantidade de repetição de um item

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Tenho uma tabela onde foram inseridos vários itens repetidos, preciso retornar todos esses itens que tem mais de um cadastro. Então fiz a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(ID),
  CODIGO,
  DESCRICAO,
  UNIDADE
FROM TB_ITEM
GROUP BY
  CODIGO,
  DESCRICAO,
  UNIDADE
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 2
```

**Situação atual da tabela:**

```
ID | CODIGO | DESCRICAO | UNIDADE
1  | 0098   | Teste A   | UN
2  | 0098   | Teste A   | UN
3  | 0098   | Teste A   | UN
4  | 0098   | Teste A   | UN
5  | 0098   | Teste B   | CX
6  | 0098   | Teste B   | CX
7  | 0098   | Teste B   | CX
8  | 0098   | Teste B   | CX
9  | 0098   | Teste B   | CX
10 | 0098   | Teste B   | CX
```

**Resultado esperado**

```
QTDE | CODIGO | DESCRICAO | UNIDADE
4    | 0098   | Teste A   | UN
6    | 0098   | Teste B   | CX
```

A tabela real possui milhares de itens repetidos, porem fiz uma amostragem do meu resultado e ele pareceu me dar um falso resultado. Alguem pode me dizer se essa é a abordagem correta da consulta?

Comment: Ao meu ver a `query` está correta, consegue filtrar uma linha e para poder comparar a diferença entre elas e assim triar o problema?

Comment: @Bulfaitelo não consegui entender sua dúvida

Comment: Você precisa retornar os registros que possuem mais de um cadastro, correto? o seu `HAVING COUNT(ID) > 2` está retornando apenas registros que possuem 3 pra cima, é isso mesmo? Se você colocar `HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1` não resolveria?

Comment: Sua `QUERY`parece estar correta mesmo, até porque, se você adicionar um item qualquer diferente dos demais, ele não virá na consulta. 
Ou se você alterar o `HAVING COUNT(ID) > 2`para `HAVING COUNT(ID) > 5`, verá que só irá trazer a `Teste B`

Comment: @AdrianoGomes O que você deseja saber é quantos itens diferentes (par DESCRICAO, UNIDADE) possuem o mesmo valor para CODIGO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se pretende ter os items que têm mais do que **um** cadastro então terá que alterar o `COUNT`:

```
SELECT      COUNT(1) AS QTDE
        ,   CODIGO
        ,   DESCRICAO
        ,   UNIDADE
FROM        TB_ITEM
GROUP BY    CODIGO
        ,   DESCRICAO
        ,   UNIDADE
HAVING      COUNT(1) > 1
```

Provavelmente era por isso que lhe dava um falso resultado.